# Estimate property of individual based on properties of other members of group

Tags: estimation, sampling, estimators

I want to estimate the nationality of a person from the nationalities of the other members of that person's family. I am looking for ideas / pointers for the following:

1. How can I know if his family is a good sample for estimating nationality?
2. What estimators I should use (e.g., mode or most common value)?

Comment: This seems like less of a methodological question & more of a question for people who are expert in this area. What does it mean to "estimate [someone's] nationality"? How could someone's nationality differ from their families? Are you wondering if someone is adopted?

Comment: I am looking for possible methods for estimations. For example, if 90% of the people in his family are American, then he is probably american (say with a probability of 0.9).

I am looking for a way to find this answer in a principled way

Comment: For this to be answerable you need to give a context where "estimation of nationality" is a useful concept.

Comment: @gung: "How could someone's nationality differ from their families?" Easily, for example, me and my wife have different nationalities! It depends of course what you mean by "family",  in my extended family there must be at least six nationalities!